# using .each() function to apply different css on different classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have different classes like `.height-half` of `height-full` etc etc.
i am using them all to calculate `width` property and apply them on each using jquery .each();

I can calculate the width properly but problem is to apply theme on the above mentioned classes:

```
var masonryImgHeight = $("[class*='height-']");
masonryImgHeight.each( function ( index,elem ) {
    console.log(2);
    var elemWidth = $( this ).width();
    console.log( elemWidth );
    var heightFull        = elemWidth,
        heightHalf        = Math.floor(0.5*elemWidth),
        heightOneThird    = Math.floor((1/3)*elemWidth),
        heightOneFourth   = Math.floor((1/4)*elemWidth),
        heightOneFifth    = Math.floor((1/5)*elemWidth),
        heightTwoThird    = Math.floor((2/3)*elemWidth),
        heightThreeFourth = Math.floor((3/4)*elemWidth);

        console.log( heightThreeFourth );

    switch( masonryImgHeight ){
        case( ".height-full" ):
            $( this ).css({
               'max-height' : heightFull
            });
        break;

        case( ".height-half" ):
            $( this ).css({
                'max-height' : heightHalf
            });
        break;
    }
});
```

so what can i do now??

Answer (score 0):

`masonryImgHeight` is a jQuery object, a collection of elements, not a string representing the className.

If you want the className, you can use `elem.className` but that returns all of them if they have more than one, or you can use `hasClass` to see if they have a certain class

```
$("[class*='height-']").each( function ( index,elem ) {

    var elemWidth = $( this ).width();

    var heightFull        = elemWidth,
        heightHalf        = Math.floor(0.5*elemWidth),
        heightOneThird    = Math.floor((1/3)*elemWidth),
        heightOneFourth   = Math.floor((1/4)*elemWidth),
        heightOneFifth    = Math.floor((1/5)*elemWidth),
        heightTwoThird    = Math.floor((2/3)*elemWidth),
        heightThreeFourth = Math.floor((3/4)*elemWidth);



    if ( $(elem).hasClass("height-full") ) {

         $(elem).css({ 'max-height' : heightFull });

    } else if ( $(elem).hasClass("height-half") ) {

        $( this ).css({ 'max-height' : heightHalf });

    }
});
```